# org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: distinct near line 1, column 17

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am trying to execute following Query in Repository using Query method. I want unique Slocation and that result should be in `JSON` format(key, value)

**Here is my code**

```
@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Integer>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Account> {

    // Load location
    @Query("select new map (distinct(a.slocation) as slocation) from Account a where a.slocation !=null")
    Set<Account> findSlocation();
```

**Error**

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: distinct near line 1, column 17 [select new map (distinct(a.slocation) as slocation) from com.spacestudy.model.Account a where a.slocation !=null]
```

Can any one tell me how to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
@Query("select new map (a.slocation) from Account a where a.slocation !=null group by slocation")
```

Comment: I got expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I got one more solution in that I removed distinct and added `Set` instead of `List`

```
@Query("select new map (a.slocation as slocation) from AccountModel a where a.slocation !=null")    
    Set<AccountModel> findBySlocation();
```